# How can I print all extra-vars before playbook is started

Tags: variables, debugging, ansible

I have wired problem with running ansible

I'd like to print to log or anywhere else the `extra-vars` I'm executing the playbook with.

I am running the following command:

```
ansible-playbook /foo/main.yml --extra-vars "main_playbook=app_install  start_path=work" --extra-vars  {"db_config":{"db_multi_config":["value1","value2"]}}'
```

with the following `main.yml` playbook

```yaml
- name: start playbook
  import_playbook: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ main_playbook}}/{{ start_path}}.yml"
```

I'd like to print the values of all `extra-vars` passed on the command line before it gets to `main.yml`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you know the names of the variables, you just can add a "debug: msg='{{ start_path }}'" task "when: start_path is defined".

Comment: no i want to print all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information in the output running ansible in full debug mode:

Given the following `test.yml` playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
```

and running it with the command:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -vvvv -e toto=bla -e '{"test1":2}'
```

I get the following result (see the debug lines for playbook before play starts)

```
ansible-playbook [core 2.11.3] 
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True
No config file found; using defaults
The vault password file /home/user/bin/vault-keyring-client is a client script.
Executing vault password client script: /home/user/bin/vault-keyring-client --vault-id avaultid1
The vault password file /home/user/bin/vault-keyring-client is a client script.
Executing vault password client script: /home/user/bin/vault-keyring-client --vault-id avaultid2
The vault password file /home/user/bin/vault-keyring-client is a client script.
Executing vault password client script: /home/user/bin/vault-keyring-client --vault-id avaultid3
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: test.yml **********************************************************************************************************************
Positional arguments: test.yml
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('/etc/ansible/hosts',)
extra_vars: ('toto=bla', '{"test1":2}')
forks: 5
1 plays in test.yml

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: do i need to set gather_facts:false  ?

Comment: Do you want to gather facts from your target(s) or not? I put it to false on all my examples - and actually all my playbooks - if not needed just to gain some time running them.

Comment: It looks like there's a typo in the post: fasle -> false. I can't fix it with an edit, since it's too short.

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate extra vars from all other vars, because they are merged. But you can see all variables for the host. (except for `setup` facts, which you can browse separately with `-m setup`).

The trick is to print all variables from hostvars group for 'itself', `ansible_host`:

```
ansible -i inventory -e extra_vars_here -m debug -a 'msg={{hostvars[inventory_hostname]}}' all
```

(replace `all` with specific hostname if you wish).

If you are overwhelmed, you can filter it with `.keys()`: `hostvars[inventory_hostname].keys()`.